# Deploy docker [kubernet]

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, circleci

I am using kubernet with circleci to deploy docker. When I run the command `"./bin/kubectl rollout status deployments/prj5-deploy --timeout=2700s"` it runs for about 20 minutes and gives an error:

```
#!/bin/sh -eo pipefail
cd .circleci/ansible
cat inventory.txt
ansible-playbook -i inventory.txt deploy-application.yml

[web]
54.237.82.69
54.226.214.135

PLAY [Deploy application] ******************************************************

TASK [build] *******************************************************************
changed: [54.237.82.69]

TASK [if successful] ***********************************************************

Too long with no output (exceeded 40m0s): context deadline exceeded
```

Sometimes it's like this:

```
TASK [if successful] ***********************************************************
fatal: [54.210.76.165]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "./bin/kubectl rollout status deployments/****-deploy --timeout=3600s", "delta": "0:21:34.424507", "end": "2023-07-13 12:55:14.013552", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2023-07-13 12:33:39.589045", "stderr": "error: deployment \"****-deploy\" exceeded its progress deadline", "stderr_lines": ["error: deployment \"****-deploy\" exceeded its progress deadline"], "stdout": "Waiting for deployment \"****-deploy\" rollout to finish: 1 out of 4 new replicas have been updated...\nWaiting for deployment \"****-deploy\" rollout to finish: 1 out of 4 new replicas have been updated...\nWaiting for deployment \"****-deploy\" rollout to finish: 1 out of 4 new replicas have been updated...\nWaiting for deployment \"****-deploy\" rollout to finish: 2 out of 4 new replicas have been updated...
```

**Here is the deploy script: deploy-application.yml:**

```
- name: "Deploy application"
  hosts: web[0]
  user: ubuntu
  gather_facts: false
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: build
      shell: "./bin/kubectl set image deployments/prj5-deploy prj5-app=shalltearbloodfallen01/prj5-deploy:master"
      args:
        chdir: $HOME  

    - name: if successful
      shell: "./bin/kubectl rollout status deployments/prj5-deploy --timeout=2700s"
      args:
        chdir: $HOME
```

**prj5-deploy:**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: prj5-deploy
  labels:
    app: prj5-app
spec:
  paused: false
  replicas: 4
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: prj5-app
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
        maxSurge: 0
        maxUnavailable: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: prj5-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: prj5-app
          image: shalltearbloodfallen01/prj5-deploy
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

**config.yml**

```
  deploy-docker:
    docker:
      - image: python:3.7-alpine3.11
    steps:
      - checkout
      - add_ssh_keys:
          fingerprints: ["xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"]
      - attach_workspace:
          at: ~/
      - run:
          name: Install dependencies
          command: |
            apk add --update ansible
      - run:
          name: deploy image docker
          no_output_timeout: 40m
          command: |
            cd .circleci/ansible
            cat inventory.txt
            ansible-playbook -i inventory.txt deploy-application.yml
```

How do I fix it    ?

Comment: That seems like the `kubectl rollout status` command isn't completing.  However, `kubectl set image ...` to the same fixed value that it already has won't do anything at all.  Is your Pod actually starting up (does `kubectl get pod` show something in CrashLoopBackOff status, maybe)?  Can you use a unique tag per build, instead of trying to reuse the fixed name `master`?

Comment: @DavidMaze 
When I get pods the result is like this.
How can I show it in more detail than Circleci ?

```TASK [get pods] ****************************************************************

changed: [54.237.82.69]```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding readiness probes to your containers.  Without those, Kubernetes doesn't know when a pod is "ready" so that it can start routing traffic to it and then move on to the next.

On an architectural note, you might consider separating your CI process (Circle CI) from your CD process (in your case calls to kubectl directly).  Consider using a tool like ArgoCD to handle the CD aspect of your CI/CD pipeline.